# I want to find a record from cached list using key in @Cacheable or any other mechanism

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

Hi there i need help I'm new to caching data. I'm using ehcache in spring application using xml configuration and I want to use different keys on different method to find same record. Suppose, one method is annotated like this:

```
@Cacheable(value="getCustomerByAreaId",key="T(java.lang.String).valueOf(#areaid)")
public  List<Customer> getCustomerByAreaId(String areaid) {
    //code 
    return customerList;
}
```

it will return all the customers having same area id. This list will be stored in the cache as each customer have unique customer id. Can I use some mechanism to fetch single customer record from cache= getCustomerByAreaId based on customer id.

`@Cacheable(value="getCustomerByAreaId",key="T(java.lang.String).valueOf(#customerId)")
    public  Customer getCustomerById(long customerId) {
    // code 
    return customer;
    }`

I know if I make key like this it will enter a new record in the cache (getCustomerByAreaId) with the new key. 
Instead I want to fetch record from list that is already being cached.

If it is possible can I do this using xml or java.

I'm using ehcache version 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible simply by using Ehcache APIs or Spring's caching abstraction.

If you want to achieve this, you will have to program your own logic to cache the list but also its elements individually.